# WHERE Query gives "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
  try
   {
      $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wba', 'root', '');
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
      echo 'Połączenie nie mogło zostać utworzone: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }
   $db->exec("set names utf8");
   $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM atrakcje WHERE `akceptacja` !=1 ORDER BY ID DESC");


      foreach($stmt as $row)
      {
        echo "<div class='pure-u-1' style='background:#ecf0f1; border:0px; margin-bottom:20px;'>";
        echo "<h2>".$row['tytul']."</h3>";
        echo "<h3>Blok: ".$row['blok']."</h2>";
        echo "<p style='padding:15px;'>".$row['opis']."<br><br><i style='float:right; padding-right:10px;'>".$row['imienazwisko']." \"".$row['ksywka']."\"</i></p>";
        echo "</div>";
      }
      $stmt->closeCursor();
```

I use the code like this. And i  get

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

on line 31 foreach($stmt as $row)

Comment: `$stmt` will be a result object and not an array. Need to make a WHILE loop. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: It would seem your query is failing and `$stmt` is `false` and not an `PDOStatement` object. You should check why it is failing by adding / enabling error handling.

Comment: I noticed that and updated my link.

Comment: @Twisty In that same page: `A nice feature of PDO::query() is that it enables you to iterate over the rowset returned by a successfully executed SELECT statement.`

Comment: You can also get PDO to throw exceptions. Put this after you open your connection: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Have not used PDO much, so that's for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments. I found out my error was misspell in database.